# Is it possible to have F# module abbreviations in a function or value binding?

Tags: f#

In the following ML extract (taken from the [Effective ML talk](http://vimeo.com/14313378)), there is a module abbreviation inside a value binding expression.  Is it possible to do the equivalent in F#?  *I know you can do module abbreviations, I am specifically interested if you can do them "inline" like this.*

```
let command =
  let default_config = { exit_code = 0; message = None } in
  let flags = 
    let module F = Command.Flag in
    [ F.int    "-r" (fun cfg v -> { cfg with exit_code = v });
      F.string "-m" (fun cfg v -> { cfg with message   = v });
    ]
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this feature is not available in F#. You can only do top-level module abbreviations (as you say) using:

```
module F = Command.Flag
```

You can write these in the middle of a source file, but they have to be at the top-level and their scope is always going to be until the end of a file (or until another definition that hides `F`). Perhaps if you used this and then had another definition *hiding* `F`, it would have similar effect. For example:

```
module L = List
[0 .. 9] |> L.map ((*) 2) // Uses functional `List.map`

module L = Seq    
[0 .. 9] |> L.map ((*) 2) // Uses lazy `Seq.map`
```

I agree taht this would be a useful feature in many cases - on the other hand, the F# programming style is sufficiently different from ML, so the advices from Effective ML talk may not directly map to F# programming. If you *need* to make something a local definition, then the best option would be to define it as an F# object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Tomas! The talk advice was "Open few modules" ([code in this blog post](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/?q=node/85)) so the local abbreviation was just a way of making the module in use locally obvious and terse.  I guess this feature would be a minor plus, but like you say what we have is enough.

Comment: I see how this would be useful - especially if you could do the same with .NET namespaces too. Sometimes I just have incredible number of various `open` declarations at the top of a file and no idea if I need them. Better tooling could help with this too though (i.e. remove unnecessary `open` declarations automatically).

Comment: Yes, removing unused `open` declarations automatically would be useful.  It is one of the features I suggested for the F# ReSharper plugin.  Still, the advice in the talk makes sense to me.  Code *readability* can be enhanced if you think carefully about which modules you open and which you reference by full name in the code.